# MulVal: how to implement attack graph using mulval

Tags: java, security

I'm trying to use the Mulval tool to generate the attack graph,

I run the attack graph by using this command 
/home/zaid/mulval/utils/graph_gen.sh /home/zaid/mulval/testcases/3host/input.P -p

but I got this error message:

> "the attack-graph generator has not compiled, or the MULVALROOT environment variable is not set appropriately!"

How can I solve it?

Comment: I suggest you compile the attack-graph generator and set the appropriate MULVALROOT environment variable.

Comment: the way that i did is

"/home/zaid/mulval/utils/graph_gen.P /home/zaid/mulval/testcases/input.P -v -v"

is that correct?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mre] of what you were doing at the time you got this error message.

Comment: Hi Zaid, I am getting the same error. Although I compiled mulval set the mulvalroot variable. How did you solve this issue?